# Naming sound files

Tags: file-naming

Hello,

I would like a recommendation regarding naming a sound files.

My problem is that I end up having huge names after doing many processing and also at the end I look at the name I gave and have no idea about what it sounds like.

For example, say I have a Metro recording, I start working with a small edit of it, say pitch shift it, add reverb, then convolve it with another sound etc.

What would be the best way of naming this kind of procedures?

thanx,
panjethro

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure it's different for everyone, but once I start mixing and rendering out specific SFX, I tend to name them for what they represent or will be used for, not the original sound source, and append with some other characteristics. Examples include "button_touchRelease_sharpClicky_v1," "drone_analog_spectralBlur+800c," "blaster_light_sizzle-2o," (+800c = +800 cents pitch shift, -2o = minus two octaves pitch shift), what have you. When processing chains get long, my names get more subjective: "blaster_light_sparkly_v4," "buttonPress_heavyThunk," etc. Time permitting, I like putting the original sound source and processing notes in a metadata field, so I can backtrack in case of session corruption or creating a larger family of sounds if they get approved.

Answer (score 0):

I name the sound according to the source and action that the sound is representing rather than what made it.  I include the source and modifications as part of the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

i also name it by what is in there: Forrest_Birds_Churchbells_Light_Wind_01 or like Iain McGregor said..... what is sounds like....